# Crystal check if subclass of list of classes

Tags: crystal-lang

So what I want to do is check if a raised error is a subclass of a list of specific Exceptions at runtime. Users can hand in an Array of Exceptions at runtime.

I thought I'd just use `is_a?` and it works as expected against a single class.

```
class A < Exception; end
class B < A; end
class C < Exception; end
class D < Exception; end

begin
  raise B.new
rescue e
  puts e.is_a? A
end
```

But if I then use an array of Exceptions to check, it doesn't work anymore

```
monitored = [A, C]
begin
  raise B.new
rescue e
  monitored.each do |exception_class|
    puts e.is_a? exception_class
  end
end
```

The error I get is `Syntax error in eval:24: expecting token 'CONST', not 'exception_class'` with line 24 being `puts e.is_a? exception_class`.

`puts typeof(exception_class)` in the loop prints `Exception:Class` as expected.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is not possible for the exact case mentioned in the question with the current compiler implementation:
https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/2060#issuecomment-309711343

Answer (score 1):

> so what I want to do is check if a raised error is a subclass of a list of specific Exceptions.

You can rescue by type(s):

```
begin
  raise B.new
rescue e : A | C
  puts "A or C"
rescue B
  puts "B"
rescue
  puts "any other kind of exception"
end
```

which prints

```
# => A or C
```

Comment: Hmm, yeah that would work if the list of exceptions is knows at compile time, but I want users to be able to hand in an Array of Exceptions and check this at runtime

Comment: Then you could use the class names or better unique ids to identify exception types. User-facing configuration should be decoupled from internal names.